# Regex to replace a number with another number using sed command fails

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to replace a number with another number in an xml file using the `sed` command. The particular parameter `<l_num>` takes a value between `0` and `16`. So, I used regex to get this done:

```
sed -i -r 's/<l_num>\b^[0-9]([0-9]*)$\b</<l_num>5</g' test.xml
```

The above gives an input 5 and should be able to give an output as a line in the `test.xml` as the following, replacing any number between 0 and 16 that is already there:

```
<l_num>5</lnum>
```

This doesn't seem to work for some reason. The expected output is 0 to 16 and without any leading zeroes for the single digits. For example, if I replace the 5 above with 05, it shouldn't update the xml file when I do this:

```
sed -i -r 's/<l_num>\b^[0-9]([0-9]*)$\b</<l_num>05</g' test.xml
```

What could be possibly wrong here?

Comment: Do not use `\b^` and `$\b`. [`sed -i -r 's/<l_num>[0-9]+</<l_num>5</g'`](http://rextester.com/IKK30564) will do. `\b`  word boundary is unnecessary here, and `^` only matches the start of line and `$` matches the end of line.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That works, but it takes leading zeroes too. How can I avoid that? Other than taking care of it in the input, is there a way I can avoid it being written at all?

Comment: @Cyrus I have updated the post.

Comment: What do you mean? Please add an example with leading 0s and the expected result.

Comment: sed is the wrong tool for parsing html/xml

Comment: it seems like you're trying to replace any number with `5`.  Where are the leading zeros coming into the picture?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have added the example.

Comment: @glennjackman Hey, why do you say that? What other alternatives are there?

Comment: @skrowten_hermit The *<l_num>05<* in the replacement is what you tell the regex engine to replace the found match with. If you do not want to replace with it, you shouldn't specify this replacement in the first place.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I understand that it is up to the user to avoid giving leading zeroes but I'm just curious that if that could be taken care of. Like say for example not writing the value if there is a leading zero. Coz '05' and '5' are different when this value are considered as strings which will corrupt the value. If there's no solution in regex, I think I got the answer.

Comment: That check should be done before passing to the regex replacement. As for glenn's remark, you can really think of a better tool to parse XMLs. E.g. [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php). With it, you may use `xml ed -u "//l_num" -v "5" file.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is not the best tool to manipulate XML files. You might use [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) and get what you need using `xml ed -u "//l_num" -v "5" file.xml` (that is, `ed`it the XML file by looking for `l_num` nodes and `u`pdating their `v`alues with `5`.

If you do not want to replace when the replacement value is `05`, you should run this check before using the replace command.

As for your regex, the issue is in using `\b` (word boundary) and `^`/`$` anchors inside the pattern. All you need to fix that code is `sed -i -r 's/<l_num>[0-9]+</<l_num>5</g' file` since `\b` word boundary is plain unnecessary here, `^` only matches the start of line and `$` matches the end of line. The `[0-9]([0-9]*)` - that matches a digit and then 0 or more digits -  can be re-written as `[0-9]+` in POSIX ERE syntax (where `+` can be used to match 1 or more occurrences of the quantified atom). In GNU `sed`, you may also use `\+` in POSIX BRE syntax, when you are not using `-r` option with `sed`.